# Hypothesis test in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, hypothesis-test

I'm using SciPy to perform Wilcoxon test and Friedman test. For example, I have 3 groups of samples.

```
sample1 = [0.76623377, 0.77922078, 0.71428571, 0.63636364, 0.7012987,  0.66233766, 0.72727273, 0.67532468, 0.63157895, 0.77631579]    
sample2 = [0.80519481, 0.76623377, 0.71428571, 0.71428571, 0.71428571, 0.72727273, 0.85714286, 0.74025974, 0.67105263, 0.77631579]
sample3 = [0.85714286, 0.74025974, 0.68831169, 0.77922078, 0.74025974, 0.77922078,0.80519481, 0.7012987,  0.73684211, 0.76315789]
```

If I apply **Wilcoxon test** for sample 1 and sample 2, using:

```
from scipy.stats import wilcoxon
t_stat, p = wilcoxon(sample1, sample2)
```

I get the error:

> sample 1 is unequal to sample 2.

If I apply **Friedman test** for all 3 samples, using:

```
from scipy.stats import friedmanchisquare
stat, `p = friedmanchisquare(sample1, sample2, sample3)
```

I get the accept: `sample 1 = sample 2 = sample3`

How is that possible? Any explanations?

Attach the python output here:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure?  I have installed scipy in a fresh conda environment and I don't get any of those errors.  Could you provide a complete example rather than snippets?  I do get a warning about sample sizes being too small for normal approximation but that is all.

Comment: Hi Thanks. It is strange. I attached my notebook output at the end of the original post (you need click the image link I think view it)

Answer (score 0):

> If I apply Wilcoxon test for sample 1 and sample 2... I get the error "sample 1 is unequal to sample 2".

I don't get this error message either, and I don't see it in the SciPy codebase. I've looked, and I don't think this error was emitted previously. There has been "The samples x and y must have the same length." and "Unequal N in wilcoxon. Aborting.", but even these would not be emitted because the sample lengths *are* equal.

> If I apply Friedman test for all 3 samples... I get the accept: `sample 1 = sample 2 = sample3`

SciPy also doesn't report this. These messages must have been emitted by the rest of the code you were running.

I think the confusion is that the messages "sample 1 = sample 2 = sample3" and "95% Probably the same distribution" (as seen in the screenshot) were misleading. When the p-value is greater than a chosen significance level, it simply means that the test will not be interpreted as evidence against the null hypothesis. This is very different from a conclusion that the samples were drawn from the same distribution. So if the author's chosen confidence level was 95%, the `wilcoxon` test result could be interpreted as evidence against the null hypothesis, but the `friedmanchisquare` test was inconclusive. That's OK.